# How to toggle a cursor's visibility in c#

Tags: c#, visibility

I'm making a game in windows visual studios express and can't figure out how to make the cursor invisible when the game starts and when you lose to make it visible again.

Answer (score 1):

The `Cursor.Hide()` and `Cursor.Show()` methods from the namespace `System.Windows.Forms` should address your needs.

Link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.cursor.hide(v=vs.110).aspx